# How to play streaming audio file in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, audio-streaming

How to play streaming audio file in iphone?

I am trying to make an app which can play audio file from web server with  Play Pause and stop functionality....
can any one have any idea about this ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a lot simpler now with the advent of AVFoundation. Look at the [AVPlayer class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It works great for streaming audio.

Answer (score 0):

Check Matt Gallagher work:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html

If this is more that you're willing to, the easy answer would be HTTP Live Streaming.